# RHEL7 server won't boot after restart - "Failed to start LSB"

Tags: boot, rhel7

I have a RHEL7 server that has been running for the past couple weeks, but it won't come back up after a restart now. I have daily snapshots, but all of them seem to be affected by the same problem.

This server is running a Drupal installation with MariaDB and Postfix.

Here is a screenshot of what it ends up hanging on: [image: http://imgur.com/qG3t4gw]

I'm not sure what changes were made that could have done this. There were some file permission changes, but shouldn't have been anything outside of drupal files. I'm really just looking for a place to start.

Also, if there's any sort of generic recovery script that I could run, that would be awesome.

Comment: the first problem you need to look, is why your network service failed to start

Answer (score 0):

In grub, edit the kernel command line and append  `systemd.unit=rescue.target`. The system will then boot to single-user mode with a shell and you can begin checking the logs to determine the actual cause of the problem.

[image]